# Call a DOS command and redirect the output to a file

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-macros

I'd like to have a macro in Visual Studio 2005 that calls a DOS command and redirects the output (stdout and stderr) to a file.  Just calling the command and ">" redirecting it will not capture stderr, so there are two parts to this:

1. calling a DOS command
2. capturing both stderr and stdout to a file during that call

I'd then like to open this file in Visual Studio after the command completes.

I'm new to Visual Studio 2005 macro writing, and VB/VBA, so that's the kind of help that I'm looking for.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3):

In DOS, > or 1> is stdout, and 2> is stderr.  So, you could say

`myprog.exe 1> out.txt 2> err.txt`

to send them to separate files, or

`myprog.exe 1>2> both.txt`

to send them to both.

In VB/VBA, you could use the [Shell](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/shell.htm) command to call this (assuming you didn't know that already).